# Fill in Word document from a excel spreadsheet with the ability to select which row(s) to be used to generate the doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm struggling for the last 9 hrs trying to create a process that will allow me to auto fill in a Word doc(Template) with information from a excel spreadsheet. I've mapped the word doc to best of my ability using `<<>>` to match the needed infor from the spreadsheet. But when the Macro is ran it continues the replicate only the some of the data in the first row and the only way to stop the replication is to stop word from the "task manager". Also, I can't figure how to select just the row(s) that I would like to be used to generate the word doc...I'm burnt out at this point.

Please help me.

This is the VBA I'm working with.

````
Sub CreateWordDocuments()
Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, DaysSince, FrDays, ToDays As Long
Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date
Dim WordDoc, WordApp, OutApp, OutMail As Object
Dim WordContent As Word.Range
With Sheet1

 If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
   MsgBox "Please select a correct template from the drop down list"
   .Range("G3").Select
   Exit Sub
 End If
   TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
   TemplName = .Range("G3").Value 'Set Template Name
   DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

   'Open Word Template
   On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
   Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   'Launch a new instance of Word
   Err.Clear
   'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
   Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
   End If


   LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table
       For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
               DaysSince = .Range("M" & CustRow).Value
               If TemplName <> .Range("N" & CustRow).Value And Row >= FrDays And DaysSince <= ToDays Then
                               Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                               For CustCol = 5 To 13 'Move Through 9 Columns
                                   TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
                                   TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                                    With WordDoc.Content.Find
                                       .Text = TagName
                                       .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                                       .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                                       .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
                                    End With
                               Next CustCol

                       If .Range("I3").Value = "PDF" Then
                                      FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("E" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("F" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf" 'Create full filename & Path with current workbook location, Last Name & First Name
                                      WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
                                      WordDoc.Close False
                                  Else: 'If Word
                                      FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("E" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("F" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
                                      WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
                                  End If
                                  .Range("V" & CustRow).Value = TemplName 'Template Name
                                  .Range("W" & CustRow).Value = Now

                                          WordDoc.Close


           End If '3 condition met
       Next CustRow
       WordApp.Quit
End With
End Sub```
````

Comment: First of all you need a `On Error Goto 0` instead of `Err.Clear`, otherwise the error reporting stays disabled and you won't ever see if something goes wrong behind this line ([VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)). `Err.Clear` just clears the error but if another error occurs you cannot see it because `On Error Resume Next` is still active! Tell us if there are errors after fixing that.

Comment: Further `Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date` will only declare `LastAppDt As Date` but `CurDt As Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim CurDt As Date, LastAppDt As Date` or it is `Variant` by default. Check this for all your variables and update the code in your question. • Finally you might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) to improve your question.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Comment: Note that this might not fix your actual issue. But it has to be fixed anyway, or you might not be able to find and fix the actual issue unless the mentioned points are fixed. So this is just the first step on your way to identify your problem.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested, but I'm getting an error.  "Variable not defined"

Comment: In which code do you get the error? Please [edit] and update the code in your question.

Comment: There's an edit link below the question which can be used to make changes to the content of the question. Please use that to update the question to the code you're currently using. Include the error message and indicate which line of code is triggering the error.

Comment: Also, when you're getting this kind of error it's an indication that `Option Explicit` may not be at the top of the code page. Make sure to add that. It may also help you when asking here to review the topic [mcve]. Since people will not have your files and cannot look over your shoulder (nor do they want your files) you need to provide enough information for them to be able to reproduce what you're doing.

Comment: A rather different approach would be to use an Excel-driven mailmerge with a suitable filter so that only the relevant records are processed. For some code to get you started, see *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: I was able to successfully fill in my word template by using the mail merge feather and inserting the correct merge field to pull the date from my spreadsheet. I'm able to this all from word. Is it possible to execute this from excel with the ability to select on demand, dynamic row numbers ie. From: 120 To:127 etc or select individual row numbers. Using maybe a Macro or something?